# Why tomcat7 can't read my context.xml?

Tags: solr, tomcat7

I'm trying to integrate apache solr4.5 with tomcat7.0.

Here is my prob, I make a directory named "solr" under $CATALINA_BASE/webapps, and create an context.xml under the path, which the directory structure looks like.

**$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/solr/META-INF/context.xml**

The context.xml looks like as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Context docBase="/solr/home/root/solr.war">
     <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/solr/home/root" />
</Context>
```

I was expecting when I visit "localhost:8080/solr/", the solr webapp should work fine, but what I got is some errors like this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /solr/

type Status report

message /solr/

description The requested resource (/solr/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

But according to the apache tomcat7.0 document,

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> 1. In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML
>      attribute) this may be copied to
>      $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>      application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> 2. In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context
>      path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>      file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take
>      precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web
>      application's META-INF directory.
> 3. Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml.

So, please anyone give me some clues, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the catalina log file located in /logs, you will probably see some errors from Solr, one of which will be:

```
 SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

This is due to a change in the way that logging in general is now implemented within Solr as of version 4.3. Please refer to [SolrLogging - Using the example logging setup in containers other than Jetty](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#Using_the_example_logging_setup_in_containers_other_than_Jetty) for the necessary steps to setup logging within Tomcat.

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I know that the SolrLogging is seperated from the solr.war, so the problem is not the error of filterStart. Actually I can run solr well with the second method by declaring my context in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/solr.xml, but I just don't get it why I can't make it with the first method mentiod in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your [`context.xml`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) (for all webapps) or `solr.xml` (solr only) file in `Catalina/localhost` folder instead.

For instance:

```
<Context docBase="webapps/solr.war" allowLinking="true" reloadable="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Troubleshooting:

- check your logs, e.g.:

  ```
  cd /var/log/tomcat? && tail -f *.log *.out *.txt
  ```